# C programming good practice or not ?

Tags: c

I have written a small piece of code to calculate quadratic equations, but if the discriminant is negative, i wanted it to write that there are no real numerical values for this quadratic equation. 
To make this happen, I had to call a function with a fourth parameter of 0, which i think , i have no idea why, would be a bad programming practice ? Is it the case or am i just being too picky of my code ? Thank you. (The reason I'm asking this is because i dont want to pick up some bad habits early on in my programming 'career').
Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

double quadratic_equation(double a, double b, double c, double d);

int main(void)
{
    char command[20];
    int i;

    printf("Enter your command: ");
    fgets(command, 20, stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (command[i] == '\n') {
            command[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(command, "quadratic equation") == 0) {
        double a, b, c, x;

        printf("Enter A: ");
        scanf("%lf", &a);
        printf("Enter B: ");
        scanf("%lf", &b);
        printf("Enter C: ");
        scanf("%lf", &c);

        x = quadratic_equation(a, b, c, 0); // THIS PIECE HERE MIGHT BE BAD PRACITCE ? 

        if (x == 0) {
            printf("There are no real numerical values to this quadratic equation.");
        }

        else {
            printf("------------\n");
            printf("x1 = %.2f\n", quadratic_equation(a, b, c, 1));
            printf("x2 = %.2f", quadratic_equation(a, b, c, -1));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

double quadratic_equation(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    double discriminant, x, insideroot;

    insideroot = ((b*b) - (4*a*c));

    if (insideroot < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    discriminant = sqrt(insideroot);
    x = (-b + (d * discriminant)) / (2 * a);

    return x;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help :d !

Comment: It looks as though, by calling `quadratic_equation` with d = 0, your calculation is actually `x = (-b + (0 * discriminant)) / (2 * a)`, which is just `x = -b / (2 * a)`, which doesn't actually implement the quadratic equation.

Comment: You'll notice he then calls it with `-1` and `1` which then does solve the quadratic equation. More to the point though is that what if `a` is zero?

Comment: @mattjgalloway: strictly speaking, if `a` is zero, it's not a quadratic equation, but he should definitely check for that.

Comment: Heh yes good point, silly me! Yeh the whole thing needs checks for all the error cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's not great to do. What you could do is something like this:

```
int quadratic_equation(double a, double b, double c, double *root_a, double *root_b) {
    double discriminant = ((b*b) - (4*a*c));

    if (discriminant < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (root_a != NULL) {
        *root_a = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    }
    if (root_b != NULL) {
        *root_b = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then you could call that like so:

```
double root_a;
double root_b;
int ok = quadratic_equation(a, b, c, &root_a, &root_b);
if (ok < 0) {
    // It wasn't OK. Print out an error.
} else {
    // It was OK. Print out the results.
}
```

Note that you should also check other error cases in the function and return -1 for them as well. E.g. `a` being zero.

Comment: Thank you! I used your recommendations (lol , i actually just wrote your code in my compiler :d ) and it works fine. But i have one question though. Inside the quadratic_equation function , you test if the pointer is not equal to NULL. What exactly is it good for, and when would the pointer be equal to NULL ? I tried the code without the if statements and it still worked fine . Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should check for null incase you passed in null. You could pass in null to indicate you don't want the values returned for instance. It's probably never going to happen but you should generally check for these things.

Comment: This is the method I would have suggested.  However, you should ensure that `a` is non-zero to avoid an error.  @geekkid Please accept this answer if it is the one that fixed your problem.

Comment: Yeh I was going to add in the check for a being zero, but thought there are other errors as well and didn't want to clutter the answer up with that. It should be in the final solution, though.

Answer (score 3):

This certainly is bad practice. Since the roots of a formula `a`, `b`, and `c` an be any `double` you **do** need some sort of passing.

I would suggest a parameter that is  a pointer to an int. If the pointer is `NULL` it is ignored, otherwise it will be set to 1 or 0 depending whether a real root exists:

```
double quadratic_equation(double a, double b, double c, int *root_exists) {
    double discriminant;

    discriminant = ((b*b) - (4*a*c));

    if (discriminant < 0) {
        if (root_exists != NULL) *root_exists = 0;
        return 0.0;
    }

    x = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

    if (root_exists != NULL) *root_exists = 1;

    return x;
}
```

A more rigorous approach is this:

```
typedef struct {
    int num_roots;
    double roots[2];
} quadratic_roots_t;

quadratic_roots_t quadratic_equation(double a, double b, double c) {
    quadratic_roots_t roots;
    double d;

    d = b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (d < 0.0) {
        roots.num_roots = 0;
    } else if (d == 0.0) {
        roots.num_roots = 1;
        roots.roots[0] = -b / (2 * a);
    } else {
        roots.num_roots = 2;
        roots.roots[0] = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
        roots.roots[1] = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    }

    return roots;
}
```

Comment: Although this works, it does not really use C common practices, which is to convey errors with the return value and use arguments to return data if there are multiple values that need to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the return value to indicate whether everything worked, and passing an array to the function to receive the return values:

```
enum QE_Status { QE_OK = 0, QE_NON_QUADRATIC, QE_COMPLEX_ROOTS, QE_NULL_POINTER };

enum QE_Status quadratic_equation(double a, double b, double c, double *r)
{
    double discriminant;

    if (r == 0)
        return QE_NULL_POINTER;
    if (a == 0.0)
        return QE_NON_QUADRATIC;

    discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);

    if (discriminant < 0)
        return QE_COMPLEX_ROOTS;

    discriminant = sqrt(discriminant);
    r[0] = (-b + discriminant) / (2 * a);
    r[1] = (-b - discriminant) / (2 * a);
    return QE_OK;
}
```

You can extend the system to handle numerical instability (because `b*b` is almost equal to `4*a*c`, or because `a` is very small, etc).

The calling code can then be:

```
 double a, b, c, x[2];

 if (quadratic_equation(a, b, c, x))
     ...oops, something went wrong...
```

Or:

```
 switch (quadratic_equation(a, b, c, x))
 {
 case QE_OK:
     ...print or use results in x...
     break;
 case QE_NON_QUADRATIC:
 case QE_COMPLEX_ROOTS:
     ...print appropriate error message about user's data...
     break;
 case QE_NULL_POINTER:
     ...Oops - programming error...
     break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly call it bad practice because the code is very unclear.

Firstly, you are calling the function three times, when once should be enough.

I'd consider returning/filling a list in your `quadratic_equation()` function instead of returning the roots one by one.

This would also allow you to determine if there are real roots -- if there aren't, just return an empty list.

As a whole, this would be much more elegant than your current solution, and it would eliminate the need for checking whether there are any solutions beforehand.